# No sound - Lubuntu 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard, 21.10

I used the Lubuntu 19.04, and the sound worked perfectly. I recently upgraded to Lubuntu 21.10 on a scratch install; unfortunately, no sound comes from the notebook's internal speakers, nor from the P2 connection for headphones.

I read some articles on the internet, but I couldn't solve the problem. When I access the PulseAudio volume control, I see that there is no sound output options, just written "Dummy Output". When I enter the terminal with the command "alsamixer", the first thing that appears is "this sound device does not have any controls." if I press F6 (select sound card), an option appears, "Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio", and even if I select it, nothing new happens.

I also reinstalled PulseAudio and ALSA, and used the "sudo alsa force-reload" command, restarted the system, which had no effect; I was in doubt if it would be something related to drivers, or kernel, however, I have little knowledge in this area, I don't know how I could proceed in relation to this...

The only thing that gives sound feedback is the HDMI output, as this is the only output option when connecting something to this port (in my case, I use it as a second monitor, not audio). As I don't have a USB speaker, I haven't tested the sound output through the USB ports.

If it helps, here is the output of some commands:

```
uname -a
Linux mwe-desktop1 5.13.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 15 14:21:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci
00:000.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 36)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 36)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit (rev 36)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 36)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 36)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 36)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 36)

inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor
  x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Imaging Unit
  driver: N/A
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.13.0-20-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.0 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.32 running: yes

cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [Audio ]: HdmiLpeAudio - Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio
                  Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio

lspci -v | grep -i audio
(no return)

cat /proc/asound/devices
1: : sequencer
2: [0- 0]: digital audio playback
3: [0-1]: digital audio playback
4: [0-2]: digital audio playback
5: [0]: control
33: : timer

aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 0: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 1: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Audio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audio], device 2: HdmiLpeAudio [Intel HDMI/DP LPE Audi]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

grep snd /proc/asound/modules
0 snd_hdmi_lpe_audio

lsmod | grep snd
snd_soc_sst_cht_bsw_nau8824 16384 0
snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt 28672 0
snd_sof_intel_ipc 20480 1 snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt
snd_sof_acpi 20480 1 snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp 16384 1 snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt
snd_sof 135168 3 snd_sof_acpi,snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
ledtrig_audio 16384 1 snd_sof
snd_intel_sst_acpi 20480 0
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match 49152 2 snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_acpi 16384 3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_intel_sst_core 61440 1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform 110592 1 snd_intel_sst_core
snd_hdmi_lpe_audio 28672 2
snd_intel_dspcfg 28672 2 snd_sof_acpi_intel_byt,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_intel_sdw_acpi 20480 1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_seq_midi 20480 0
snd_seq_midi_event 16384 1 snd_seq_midi
snd_soc_nau8824 65536 1 snd_soc_sst_cht_bsw_nau8824
snd_rawmidi 36864 1 snd_seq_midi
snd_soc_core 290816 4 snd_soc_sst_cht_bsw_nau8824,snd_sof,snd_soc_nau8824,snd_soc_sst_atom hifi2_platform
snd_compress 28672 1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus 16384 1 snd_soc_core
snd_seq 73728 2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_pcm_dmaengine 16384 1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm 118784 9 snd_soc_sst_cht_bsw_nau8824,snd_sof,snd_soc_nau8824,snd_sof_intel_ipc,snd_compress,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_atom_deng_pcm,sand_platine
snd_seq_device 16384 3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer 40960 2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd 94208 14 snd_seq,snd_soc_sst_cht_bsw_nau8824,snd_seq_device,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_socr_pawcm,idisnd
soundcore 16384 1 snd

cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k5.13.0-20-generic.
```

Since now, I thank you for your time and help given to resolve this issue, and sorry for the English, I used Google Translate, it's faster. As for which computer I use, it is a national one, whose brand is "Positivo", perhaps this is relevant when considering hardware issues.

**Error Messages:**
When booting the system (via the pendrive, at the time of system installation), the following messages appear:

```
sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622AB:00: error: tplg request firmware intel/sof-tplg/sof-cht-nau8824.tplg failed err: -2
sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622AB:00: you may need to download the firmware from https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/
sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622AB:00: error: failed to load DSP topology -2
sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622AB:00: ASoC: error at snd_soc_component_probe on 808622AB:00: -2
cht-bsw-nau8824 cht-bsw-nau8824: ASoC: failed to instantiate card -2
cht-bsw-nau8824 cht-bsw-nau8824: snd_soc_register_card failed -2
atomsip-isp2 0000:00:03.0: Support for Cherrytrail (ISP2401) was disabled at compile time
```

Comment: What is the make/model of the sound/audio adapter?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.

In this case, as the external monitor I use is VGA, I use an HDMI to VGA adapter; in fact, when you asked about this, I remembered that the adapter I use also has a second output, P2, for audio.

When you connect a speaker to this output (which comes from HDMI), you actually get some audio signal; anyway, it's good to know that from at least one place you can get some sound...

Comment: I find it strange that the output of the "inxi -A" command shows that there are no drivers for the audio hardware;  I had already thought that perhaps this is the problem, but I don't know how to proceed, if that is really the case;

Comment: The reason I asked for the make/model of the audio adapter is because these kinds of things usually have a hardware-specific solution. To proceed, answer the question.

Comment: The question has been edited and the output of a few more commands has been added; do any of them provide the answer sought?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem upgrading my Medion E2228T to 21.10.

It also runs on an Atom x5 and it looks like the new 5.13 kernel doesn't play well with it.

A look at dmesg took me to https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin and solved my problem. I backed up my firmware files, ran the install script and was good to go.

I now can see a working "Built-in Audio" device alongside with the "Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller" that continues to show as deactivated on sound settings / hardware. Selecting Built-in Audio makes my speakers and headphones work.